# after affect delay layer animation

Tags: after-effects

I am new to AE and I am trying to edit a Photo Album template ( its a video of a photo/videos album flipping pages ). 
I managed most of my requirements, but failed to make some of the transitions longer. ( I need the page to delay the turn because the videos are longer than the current duration ). Thanks

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Could you explain what you have tried doing and perhaps provide a sample video?

Comment: I am using this template:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HkcLwFs4nw and I am trying to add videos, but the page duration is to short

Comment: @MichaelLiebman , is there a way I can send you the AE project privately ?

Comment: Sending it outside of SE would defeat the purpose. It is better to post screenshots of the UI.

Answer (score 2):

In the composition where you drag and arrange individual pages. Pick the layer of the page you want to make longer, then click and drag that layer in the timeline to the desired length.

Comment: If you have the full project, look for "02. Product Overview" tutorial, fast forward to 1:55 min to see how it is done.